# jQuery UI Datepicker detect select

Tags: jquery

When a date is selected by the user, I want to check a condition and cancel the selection

```
onSelect: function(dateText) {
       // code to cancel selection

}
```

How do i cancel it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`beforeShowDay` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay).

So:

```
$(/*...*/).datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        if(disableCondition)
            return [true,'','You can\'t select this!'];
        else
            return [false,'',''];
    }
});
```